# custom libdrm for buildroot

Tags: customization, hardware-acceleration, buildroot

We are building a minimal FS on our platform using buildroot. We want libdrm version 2.4.60 to test our driver while buildroot is downloading libdrm version 2.4.66. Is there any way in which we can tell buildroot to use a custom library?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three ways to customize a package:

1. Use the [`_OVERRIDE_SRCDIR` feature](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#_using_buildroot_during_development). This allows you to modify the source of a package as you like.
2. Edit the package .mk file directly, i.e. `package/libdrm/libdrm.mk`, and change LIBDRM_VERSION into the version you need. You will also have to update `package/libdrm/libdrm.hash` with the correct hash, and most likely you also have to update the patches. One way of achieving this is to revert buildroot to 36e69dc2415f4bd2759c29bdd39a289b0a3776f1.
3. Create a new package with a different name, e.g. libdrm2460. The disadvantage of this approach is that if you select other packages that depend on libdrm, they will still force the build of libdrm-2.4.66.

Remember, though, that using a custom version of a package means that you will have to take care of any cross-compilation issues yourself.